# Unable to access a record of a collection of mongo using monk in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I am trying to access the data returned by the find method in monk using:

```
var collection = db.get('Workflow');
collection.find({},{},function(e,workflow){
    console.log(workflow);
    var req0 = workflow[0];  //Error here
    console.log(req0);
    console.log(req0, req.body.accountType);
});
```

The first console.log(workflow) returns me the whole record correctly which looks like a json array. However, when I am trying to access, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\routes\index.js:68:38)
at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:178:8)
at Promise.emit (events.js:117:20)
at Promise.emit (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
at Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:97:20)
at Promise.resolve (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:126:15)
at C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:163:16
at commandHandler (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:709:16)
at C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1846:9
at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\abchauhan\Desktop\Work\NodeLearning\HelloNode\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:445:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, it doesn't return array. If you only require the first record, why not try the 'limit'

```
var collection = db.get('Workflow');
collection.find({},{'limit':1},function(e,workflow){
    console.log(workflow);
    var req0 = workflow;
    console.log(req0);
});
```